# any tagged element within a div is closing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have attached: http://jsfiddle.net/75JaR/12/

What this is supposed to do is each `link` should open a div which is `closeable` by clicking outside the `div`. This works great thanks to some help here on *stackoverflow*.

However if I put anything in that `div` other than straight text it, clicking on it will close it.

I cannot  wrap text in `p, a, span` or even use an `image`, could anyone tell me why this might be?

EDIT: if you try clicking on the tagged text it will close

```
      $('.trigger').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.header-menu-container').hide();
    $(this).next('.header-menu-container').slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(e.target);
    if ($this.hasClass("header-menu-container")) return;
    if ($this.hasClass("header-menu-contents")) return;
    $('.header-menu-container').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Seems to work for me on Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome as well, if you click on something wrapped in tags it will close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the element parent div has not the class

```
 if ($this.hasClass("header-menu-container")) return;
if ($this.hasClass("header-menu-contents")) return;
```

If you click the `<p><p>`

The `<p>` has not the class and that's why it is closing

Check this fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/75JaR/13/)